# Spring Transaction Management @Transactional behavior

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, transactions, spring-transactions

I wanted to know how the Spring @Transactional will work for the following Coding scenarios. I am using Spring 4 + Hiberante 5 with Oracle 19C database for this example.

**Example 1:**

```
@Service
public class UserService {
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public void invoice() {
        createPdf();
        // send invoice as email, etc.
    }
    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public void createPdf() {
        // ...
    }
}
```

**Example 2:**

```
@Service
public class UserService {
    @Autowired
    private InvoiceService invoiceService;
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public void invoice() {
        invoiceService.createPdf();
        // send invoice as email, etc.
    }
}
@Service
public class InvoiceService {
    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public void createPdf() {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: The first one is known as a _self-call_ and doesn't go through `TransactionInterceptor` (it just uses `this` instead of the Spring transaction wrapper object), so the `@Transactional` on `createPdf()` essentially doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Example 1**: As you are calling the createPDF method from `inside` your Service, the @Transactional(REQUIRES_NEW) annotation will effectively be `ignored`. There will be no new transaction opened.

**Example 2**: As your are calling another service, which is wrapped in a transactional proxy, you will get a `new transaction`, as the annotation is respected.

You also might want to read up on this article: [Spring Transaction Management: @Transactional In-Depth](https://www.marcobehler.com/guides/spring-transaction-management-transactional-in-depth)